# Configuring Fiware PEP Proxy, Keyrock and Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma

I'm trying to integrate Keyrock and PEP Proxy in order to secure the access to the Context Broker but I'm having some issues.

What I want to achieve is that only determined users registered in Keyrock can access to the Context Broker.

I followed Fiware tutorials but in that development scene there is an application which listens on port 3000 that is registered in Keyrock. But how can I get the same result without that tutorial application? Can't I secure access to the Context Broker without an application?

If it's possible, it would be nice some help. Here you have relevant part of my docker-compose file:

```
keyrock:
    image: fiware/idm:${KEYROCK_VERSION}
    container_name: fiware-keyrock
    hostname: keyrock
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
    depends_on:
        - mysql-db
    ports:
        - "${KEYROCK_PORT}:${KEYROCK_PORT}" # localhost:3005
        - "${KEYROCK_HTTPS_PORT}:${KEYROCK_HTTPS_PORT}" # localhost:3443
    environment:
        - "DEBUG=idm:*"
        - "IDM_DB_HOST=mysql-db"
        - "IDM_DB_PASS_FILE=/run/secrets/my_secret_data"
        - "IDM_DB_USER=root"
        - "IDM_PORT=${KEYROCK_PORT}"
        - "IDM_HOST=http://localhost:${KEYROCK_PORT}"
        - "IDM_HTTPS_ENABLED=${IDM_HTTPS_ENABLED}"
        - "IDM_HTTPS_PORT=${KEYROCK_HTTPS_PORT}"
        - "IDM_ADMIN_USER=admin"
        - "IDM_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@test.com"
        - "IDM_ADMIN_PASS=1234"
    secrets:
        - my_secret_data
    healthcheck:
        interval: 5s
# Database
mysql-db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_DB_VERSION}
    hostname: mysql-db
    container_name: db-mysql
    expose:
      - "${MYSQL_DB_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_DB_PORT}:${MYSQL_DB_PORT}"
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.6
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/my_secret_data"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.18.1.5" # Allow Keyrock to access this database
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql
    secrets:
      - my_secret_data

orion-proxy:
    image: fiware/pep-proxy
    container_name: fiware-orion-proxy
    hostname: orion-proxy
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.10
    depends_on:
        - keyrock
    ports:
        - "1027:1027"
    expose:
        - "1027"
    environment:
        - PEP_PROXY_APP_HOST=orion
        - PEP_PROXY_APP_PORT=1026
        - PEP_PROXY_PORT=1027
        - PEP_PROXY_IDM_HOST=keyrock
        - PEP_PROXY_HTTPS_ENABLED=false
        - PEP_PROXY_AUTH_ENABLED=false
        - PEP_PROXY_IDM_SSL_ENABLED=false
        - PEP_PROXY_IDM_PORT=3005
        - PEP_PROXY_APP_ID= <Obtained in Keyrock>
        - PEP_PROXY_USERNAME= <Obtained in Keyrock>
        - PEP_PASSWORD= <Obtained in Keyrock>
        - PEP_PROXY_PDP=idm
        - PEP_PROXY_MAGIC_KEY=1234
```

In order to test it, I registered a test application with URL `localhost:1026` (orion context broker URL)  with a PEP Proxy (from which I got `PEP_PROXY_APP_ID`, `PEP_PROXY_USERNAME` and `PEP_PASSWORD`).

When I run the docker containers it works but the problem comes when I try to get an access token using this [bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bitergia/fiware-chanchan-docker/master/images/pep-wilma/4.3.0/auth-token.sh) (changing `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` to those obtained in the OAuth2 field of the application and `https://idm/oauth2/token` to `http://localhost:3005/oauth2/token`) with admin credentials.

I get `invalid_client: Invalid client: client is invalid` error.

If you need to see any more file just ask me.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the first question, yes, it is mandatory to create a Keyrock's application to protect Orion. You have also to create some roles and permissions in the application and assign them to the users you want. Check the FIWARE tutorial about [roles and permissions](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Roles-Permissions/tree/891f4802c1b153ef22fa536c444edb416929915e)

Regarding the "client is invalid error", I guess something went wrong in the bash script when parsing the credentials from the JSON file. I have tested hardcoding the client id, client secret and username/password in the bash script and Keyrock creates the token successfully (check also the access token display as the response of Keyrock is a JSON).